# Editing the Book Template

Tags: 7, nodes

I'd like to edit the way the Book navigation is structured.
I'd like to be able to edit the html output of the book.

I was looking for a way to do this with the book template but had no luck. Looking at book-navigation.tpl.php I did see that $tree contained the children of the current node. However it used like this

```
<?print $tree; ?>
```

I don't see a way to alter the html of how the tree is output.

Answer (score 1):

The theme hook you'll want is `menu_link__book_toc_123`, where `123`is the node ID of your book's outline node.
For the wrapping markup, use `menu_tree__book_toc_123`.

You can also find the ID by inspecting the navigation list:

[image: Book navigation list]